# Will this circuit work as a selectable frequency random-looking LED flasher?

Tags: led, counter

I am trying to create a frequency selectable LED flasher that looks random. The purpose is to make a lightning effect for a project I am working on. The voltage can be adjusted if it is insufficient. Should I use the IC outputs to switch transistors instead of lighting the LEDs directly? Will the circuit function at all? The capacitor mF ratings are arbitrary as I will tune them based on how it looks. I may also tie multiple outputs to the same LED. Should I use diodes on the output legs of the IC in this case? Any help is appreciated.

[image: Random LED Flasher Rev 1.0]

Comment: I know you say the capacitors are arbitrary, but those are some truly *enormous* capacitors.

Comment: The capacitors will be used for timing. From what I have been able to find, a 10mF cap will give flashes every .02 seconds. It may be more like 2mF, 5mF, 10mF, 20mF etc. It will be trial and error for this section. This is my first try at designing my own circuit, so I appreciate any and all input.

Comment: A farad is a truly huge amount of capacitance. Typical circuits use capacitors in the range of a few nF to a few hundred μF, with very occasional special purposes requiring things outside that range. It's very difficult and expensive to even *get* a capacitor larger than about 10 mF that's rated for any significant voltage. You should design your circuit to work with capacitors in the hundreds of μF to single-digit mF.

Comment: Sorry, I do mean uF, not mF. I wasn't paying attention to the nomenclature I was using. The capacitors I will be using are in microfarads.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet for the CD4026 shows that its outputs will overheat and fail if the 9V battery is new.

Comment: I can raise or drop the input voltage if needed. I was looking at the rated input range and figured 9V was a safe mid range voltage. Would a heat sink on the IC help with heat failure? I am worried about the milliamp rating for the IC outputs if I lower the input voltage too much. I am not great at deciphering data sheets yet. I appreciate your help.